# Error when using mice object: No applicable method for 'complete_'

Tags: r, r-mice

```r
library(mice)
md.pattern(dat1)
temp<-mice(dat1, m = 5, seed = 101)
dat1 <- complete(temp, 2)
```

> Error in UseMethod("complete_") :
> no applicable method for 'complete_' applied to an object of class "mids"

Hi, I'm trying to impute missing values using `mice` package.
But I got the above error message.
The first time I imputed missing data it worked, but when I tried again it didn't. I've tried a lot with different options (changing seed, deleting existing data or "temp" variable)

Sometimes it worked but other times it didn't.
What is the problem and solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code should work. Please provide a complete example to reproduce the problem you describe. The error message indicates that R fails to find a `complete` method for the object type that is produced by `mice`. Are you sure that the `mice` package is loaded at all times? Does it change anything if you replace `complete` with `mice::complete`?

Answer (score 14):

I think the problem here is that you should rather be using some other libraries in your program which have a function named "complete". Just typing "complete" in help menu gave me 2 other libraries (tidyr,RCurl) which have the function in the same name. As simon suggested, I tried using "mice::complete". It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dat1<-mice::complete(temp,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

`mice 3.7.5` redefines the `complete()` function as the S3 `complete.mids()` method for the generic `tidyr::complete()`.

Assuming that `mice` is attached, you should no longer see `no applicable method for 'complete_' applied to an object of class "mids"`.